# ITextSharp PDFReader crashes application (even when inside try catch)

Tags: c#, itext

ITextSharp works fine most of the time and most errors are caught within a try catch block. However, every so often it meets a file it doesn't like and the whole application crashes.

When I try to open up the pdf file from Windows I get the message

> "Can't open this file. There's a problem with the file format"

So obviously the file is corrupted.

Is there any way to catch this error?

[Link to the file on drop box](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5iq49vwsbki5tld/TimeLine.pdf?dl=0)

```
public string GetPDFText(int ScanId, String pdfPath, out int NumWords, out int NumCharacters)
    {
        string Content = "";
        NumWords = 0;
        NumCharacters = 0;

        try
        {
            //PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfPath);

            using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfPath))
            {
                StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

                for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
                {
                    ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
                    string currentText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i, strategy);
                    currentText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(currentText)));
                    text.Append(currentText);
                }

                Content = text.ToString();
                var regex = new Regex(@"\b[\s,\.-:;]*");
                var words = regex.Split(Content).Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x));
                NumWords = words.Count();
                NumCharacters = Content.Count(char.IsLetterOrDigit);
            }
        }

        catch (iTextSharp.text.DocumentException ex)
        {
            AddErrorLog(new ErrorLog(-1, ex.GetType().Name, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, ScanId, pdfPath, ex.Message, ex.TargetSite.ToString(), DateTime.Now, Environment.UserName, false));
            NumFileErrors++;
        }
        catch (iTextSharp.text.exceptions.InvalidPdfException ex)
        {
            AddErrorLog(new ErrorLog(-1, ex.GetType().Name, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, ScanId, pdfPath, ex.Message, ex.TargetSite.ToString(), DateTime.Now, Environment.UserName, false));
            NumFileErrors++;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            AddErrorLog(new ErrorLog(-1, ex.GetType().Name, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, ScanId, pdfPath, ex.Message, ex.TargetSite.ToString(), DateTime.Now, Environment.UserName, false));
            NumFileErrors++;
        }

        return Content;
    }
```

Comment: How do *you* currently try to catch the error, how does your try-catch-block look like?

Comment: Thanks for your interest @mkl - I've added the whole code block now.

Comment: Further investigation reveals that it's a StackOverflow error relating to PDFReader.

Comment: In that case: please share the faulty PDFs that cause the error, so that we can throw an `InvalidPdfException`. In recent iTextSharp versions, we try to throw more revealing exceptions, such as "a rectangle is defined by 4 values, you only have 3" instead of "index array out of bounds". The latter exception is correct: iTextSharp tries to get value the fourth value in an array that only has three values, but the former is more clear to an end user.

Comment: Does catching the stack overflow error resolve your issue? Then you should make that an answer.

Comment: I'm probably missing something obvious but I can't work out how to attach a file...

Comment: Hello @mkl, I thought you couldn't normally catch stack overflow errors, but I'm now attaching a link to the problem file.

Comment: Hello @Bruno Lowagie, Sorry for the delay in responding: vacation intervened. I've now attached the link to the offending file.

Comment: Somebody (deliberately) screwed up the file by introducing an (illegal) circular page tree. This is the fixed file: http://itextpdf.org/documents/TimeLine.pdf Your original file should not be opened by any software: it is bad to the bone. Find out who screwed it up and spank him (or her).

Comment: Hi @Bruno Lowagie, 
Thanks for the diagnosis. Is there any way to spot instances of that before they crash the application? I have very large scans/extractions running as a background process (in a Windows Service actually) and the only time I know that there's something wrong is when the service stops. Then I have to try and work out which file caused the problem. It would be good if we could "test" the files for validity before attempting to read them.

Comment: That would need some custom development. Are you an iText customer? If so, please create a ticket on our issue tracker. Are you an iText user (not paying for your use of iText), then you'll have to do this on your own. Note: [this one-minute video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHF3xcWnSD4) explains when you should be a customer.